# Indexing issue pandas data frame

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I am running a loop through my data frame index that does many things, but one of the things it does is under certain conditions change a value from a string to a list object. That list object is stored in another pandas Series, that is indexed exactly the same as the data frame being looped through. The index is confirmed unique. The index is integers. IndList is a list of the index values in the df that I want to alter

Some basic code is belowL

```
df = DataFrame(mydata)
ListSeries = pd.Series(moredata, index = df.index)

for row in df.index:
    #do lots of cool stuff here
    if row in IndList:
        df.item[row] = ListSeries[row]
        print df.item[row]
```

Now when I do this the print command spits out the list just as I would wish. Additionally when I do this:

```
df['item'].ix[805]
```

or

```
df['item'].iloc[805]
```

The list is output as 805 is in the IndList

but when I do:

```
df[['item', 'data1']].ix[805]
```

or

```
df.ix[805, ['item', 'data1']]
```

the value is as it was previously before loopinig. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I am working in iPython Notebook

Comment: see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy, you need to set using: ``df.loc[row,column] = value``, and not chained assignment. In addition, you are better off using a vectorized method or apply if you cannot vectorize.

Comment: Thanks, I had only partially paid attention to that page of the docs. I'm still not fully sure why, even after a faulty assignment I should see the desired out out some of the time. Did I create a bad copy by assigning, or did I just effectively do nothing?

Comment: I am going to say it won't ever work as its mixed-type (for the most part a single-dtyped frame will work on chained assignment). safer just to always use ``.loc``